# A problem with finding apps in the market on the Phone

Tags: google-play-store, installation

I want to install the app [Where](https://market.android.com/search?q=where&so=1&c=apps). But when I did the same search in the Android Market app on my phone, I couldn't find this app. Since my phone does not have service, I cannot install this app through the Android Market website. Does anybody know why this app does not show up on the phone? How can I install this app in this case? I couldn't find its apk file either. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Chahk's answer, there are also geographic or carrier restrictions for some apps.  These are basically up to developer, and we can only speculate as to why.  You should contact the developer.

Comment: This is a good point. Carrier restrictions could be the reason, since my phone doesn't have service.

Comment: You can try to trick the Market into bypassing the carrier restrictions.  Try the "Market Enabler" app: https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler

Answer (score 2):

Some apps have certain hardware requirements that your phone might not support (e.g. screen resolution.) The Market has the ability to filter out such apps from search results.

Comment: My phone is a Nexus One. Do you happen to know why the "Where" app is not compatible with Nexus One?